# Maven GWT production deployment - 'may need to be (re)compiled'

Tags: java, gwt, maven

Short summary: GWT compilation is running fine as part of a Bamboo plan, but the generated nocache.js contains the (re)compile message.

I'm running into a little trouble lately while changing the way the application is compiled and deployed.
Configuration:
- GWT 2.4.0
- Maven GWT plugin
- Bamboo

Running a GWT compilation on my machine everything is performing normally, can run both in dev mode and js mode.
Running a maven compilation (through eclipse - maven - run as - package) performs fine, nocache.js looks fine.
Running a command-line maven compilation on an XP machine or with a Solaris+Bamboo yields a wrong nocache.js, even though the generated htmls look ok. In fact, the *.cache.html are identical to the ones on my machine.

So the module.nocache.js on my machine contains the correct references to the uniquely named html files while the nocache.js on the affected machines(?) does not contain any such references.

GWT compiler launch options are identical on all machines. Target and war folders were cleaned on all machines.

A summary of the plan:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ myproject ---
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile (default) @ myproject ---
[INFO]    Compilation succeeded -- 639,969s
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [myproject] in [.....\myproject\target\myproject-2.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [....\myproject\war]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [14125 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: .....\myproject\target\myproject-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.1.2:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:test (default) @ myproject ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ myproject ---
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ myproject ---
```

Locally, in Eclipse, I've closed all projects except the one I'm compiling so all the dependencies are retrieved via maven. Eclipse is signalling a lot of error but I'm running from eclipse the maven goals clean and install and the result is again fine.
The resulting nocache.js files have the same time as the compilation time, they are not retrieved or left-over.

I'm stumped, somehow on the Bamboo machine the Maven GWT compile plugin has decided by its own to compile for development, I assume.

---

L.E.

Additional info, Bamboo build log. It seems to be using the standard linker and it looks the same as on the local machine:

```
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:35    [INFO]    Permutation 0 (strong name F96236D63A05E1D33308D4FE26EDA9F9) has an initial download size of 4937614 and total script size of 4937614
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:35    [INFO]    Invoking Linker RPC policy file manifest
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:35    [INFO]    Invoking Linker Standard
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker RPC log linker
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Emitting RPC log files
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker Export CompilationResult symbol maps
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker Emit compile report artifacts
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Permutation 1 (strong name B836CC45CC0786F0D04CEA25F7204F39) has an initial download size of 5220544 and total script size of 5220544
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker RPC policy file manifest
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker Standard
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker RPC log linker
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Emitting RPC log files
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker Export CompilationResult symbol maps
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker Emit compile report artifacts
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker RPC policy file manifest
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker Standard
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker RPC log linker
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker Export CompilationResult symbol maps
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Invoking Linker Emit compile report artifacts
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Linking Public artifacts into ....-SNAPSHOT
build   06-Aug-2012 20:18:36    [INFO]    Linking Deploy artifacts into ....-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/deploy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, it was a nocache.js file that was commited some time ago by mistake. Because of it, the new nocache.js never got generated or did not overwrite it.

Not exactly sure on the details of how this happened but I will not investigate further, I'm adding this only for future reference.